# The form used when calculating relative angular velocity

Tags: angular-velocity, solar-system

When calculating relative angular velocity, there are two forms.

1. $\omega_{ab}=\omega_a - \omega_b$

Some textbooks use the relative angular velocity as shown above to guide the synodic period

2. $\omega_{ab}=(v_a-v_b)/(\text{relative distance})$

However, when you express the relative angular velocity as a vector, you get the above result.

Which of the two forms is the correct expression?

Comment: How are you defining relative distance? Are you only dealing with uniform circular motion? In such motion, $v=r\omega$, but that's not true for elliptical orbital motion, however in such motion angular momentum is constant.

Comment: @PM2Ring Let's just assume circular motion in the solar system. In the formula, I need to divide the relative distances on both sides to get an expression for the relative angular velocity, but when I'm looking for the synodic period, I'm only using a angular velocity to get the relative angular velocity. I don't understand. How can you have two forms of the expression

Comment: To calculate synodic period, just use equation 1. You don't care about any distances, just the angles on the celestial sphere.

Comment: We have several questions about synodic periods on our sister site, eg https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/50549/16685